# Would this sentence be considered grammatically correct

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, american-english, modifiers

A sci-fi middle-grade suspense novel about a 14-year-old girl who must retrieve the stone, preventing the rise of a human nuclear weapon.

Comment: It is grammatically correct, but not semantically. **The** stone implies that a stone has already been mentioned. Also it's hard to picture what is "the rise of a human nuclear weapon." How does it **rise**? In a rocket? What is a non-human nuclear weapon?

Comment: It's not a sentence. Try 'It is a ...'. But please look at the Help Center; "Is this sentence correct?" questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stands out as the main problem is that "rise" is a poor word choice.

Is it the *creation* or the *detonation* of a nuclear weapon that's being averted?

[rise (noun)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rise)

> 2. an act of rising or a state of being risen: such as
>
>    a. a movement upward: **ascent**.

You could have the rise of a nuclear *superpower* or the rise of Nazi Germany/Soviet Russia, for example, as they could *ascend* in the sense of gaining more power but an inanimate object can't really be described in the same terms.

Here's how I might phrase it:

> This is the compelling story of a 14-year-old girl on a quest to find a mysterious stone, in a desperate bid to avert the **inception** of a cataclysmic human nuclear weapon.